# DAX. Obtain the value of a column based on the max value of another column

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

hope you are doing well.

I'm struggling with the following situation. I think it is easy to solve but I'm not reaching a solution because of my limited knowledge of DAX.

My scenario is the following:

I have 3 tables (I share a link below with an Excel test file so you can see it and work there):

1) "t_data" (where every register is a transaction of a spare part changed of a bus);

2) "t_actualKms" (where I have every bus with their respective actual kilometer). Related to "t_data";

3) and a "Calendar". Related to "t_data".

**What I need is to calculate the "Actual performance" of each spare part in each bus, based on the last change of it and the actual kilometers of the bus.**

The calculation (a measure) should be (if we use 2 other measures):

*Actual performance = [Actual bus kms] - [Last spare part kms]*

The [Actual bus kms] measure should take the kms from the t_actualKms table for each bus and use it to compare with the [Last spare part kms].

The [Last spare part kms] measure should take the last date a specific spare part was changed in an specific bus and bring the "Kms at change". With that then you will calculate the **Actual performance**.

Here is an Excel sample so you can test it and a tab with the goal (should be a matrix or a pivot table) of what I need.

Sample: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1a8LglB7F76SkmBgoneORWC0SZVZed9R7

Hope you can understand my problem. If you need more details please let me know.

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Andy.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [MAXX](https://dax.guide/maxx/) formula.

```
=MAXX(t_data, [Actual kms]) - MAXX(t_data, [Kms at change])
```

Important to note you need additional logic if you expect totals to work.

[image]

Comment: Amazing @Frostytheswimmer !! Can you please explain me how does it works?? I don't need the totals, in fact, it's better that they don't show anything.

Comment: I was trying it and it is showing a number in the totals for me. How is that you don't have it? As I said, it's better to no show them, because they don't have any sense. Thank you very much again!!

Comment: You should be able to turn off totals in the pivot table settings tab. Check out the documentation for a more in depth review of the MAXX function.